# React Routing with Dynamic Route Unable to find this.props.match.params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React BrowserRouter in which I have three routes, shown below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact
                       path="/"
                       component={(routeProps: object) => (
                           <Component1 toggle="Previous" {...routeProps} />
                       )}
                />
                <Route path="/active"
                       component={(routeProps: object) => (
                           <Component1 toggle="Active" {...routeProps} />
                       )}
                />
                <Route path="/items/:id"
                       render={(props) => <Component2 {...props}/>}
                />
            </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I am attempting to pass the id into Component2 as shown, in order to get an item by id with a get api call. My Component2 is shown below:

```
export default class Component2 extends React.Component<Props & RouteComponentProps, State> {

    public constructor(props: Props & RouteComponentProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: {
                //Item initialization
            }
        };
    }

    public async componentWillMount() {
        let job = await ItemService.fetch(this.props.match.params);
        this.setState({item: item});
    };


    public render() {
        let {item} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="item-details">
                <Component3 item={item}/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

However, I am receiving an error on the line containing `this.props.match.params.id`.

- The first error is if I do not include the RouteComponentProps, on `this.props.match.params` states: `Property match does not exist on type <Readonly<Props> & Readonly<ReactNode>`

  - There is another Stack Overflow post that led to the idea that you need RouteComponentProps in the ReactComponent in order to find the props, but had no explanation as of why.
- If I add the RouteComponentProps, I fix the first error but am still unable to get the id from the params. I receive the error: `property id does not exist on type {}`

After searching through questions on SO and many react routing examples, I am stuck. My end goal is to have a component (Component2) that will:

1. Be routed to when the url matches `items/:id`(i.e. `/items/3`)
2. Pass the id of 3 into that Component and call the Backend to get the item
3. Save the item from the backend call to the state(local state of Component2)
4. Pass that item from the state into children components

I also am curious in the difference between:

- `React.Component`
- `React.Component<Props>`
- `React.Component<Props, State>`
- `React.Component<Props & RouteComponentProps, State>`

as my reference to the component in the `<Route` produces errors when I switch the Component declaration with the React.Components above.

Answer (score -1):

`RouteComponentProps` has an optional generic parameter (which defaults to `{}`) to specify what the expected parameters are. The type declarations are:

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}, C extends StaticContext = StaticContext, S = H.LocationState> {
  history: H.History;
  location: H.Location<S>;
  match: match<Params>;
  staticContext?: C;
}

export interface match<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}> {
  params: Params;
  isExact: boolean;
  path: string;
  url: string;
}
```

So, if you declare the usage as `RouteComponentProps<{ id: string}>` it should type correctly.

Edit:

> I also am curious in the difference between:

For the majority of these options, it is just that if you do not specify a generic type, a type of `{}` is assumed.  So `React.Component` is equivalent to `React.Component<{}, {}>` and both props and state will be typed as an empty object.

When you have `<Props & RouteComponentProps>`, this is [an intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) that means the component props will be both `Props` and `RouteComponentProps` merged together.

Comment: Why do I even need a RouteComponentProps in the first place? Multiple tutorials (i.e. [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/) and [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params)) do not even use it.

What if I want the id as a number, not a string?

Comment: You are using TypeScript, while the examples you link to are just JavaScript - you need to declare the types of the props that are passed into your component or the TypeScript compiler will yell at you.

Comment: All route parameters are strings (because they're in the url) - if they're supposed to be a number, you'll have to check and parse/convert them.

Comment: [React Router passes the props defined in `RouteComponentProps` to your components](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) so that you can get things like the route parameters.